# ngClass style with dash in key

Tags: angularjs

I hope this saves someone a headache with styles that use dashes, especially since bootstrap has become so popular.

I am using angular 1.0.5 by way of

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
```

In the [ngClass documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass), the example is simple, but it also mentions the expression can be a map of class names to boolean values. I was trying to use the "icon-white" style on my icon as shown in the [bootstrap documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons), depending on a boolean variable.

```
<i class="icon-home" ng-class="{icon-white: someBooleanValue}">
```

The line above does not work. The class is not appended with `icon-white` when `someBooleanValue` is true. However, if I change the key to `iconWhite`, it is successfully added to the list of class values. How would one add a value with a dash?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! You should update your question to split it into a question and an answer - answering your own question is OK, and encouraged if it is helpful. That way you can accept your answer, and others searching can see that the question has a successful answer.

Answer (score 372, accepted):

After hours of hacking around, it turns out the dash gets interpolated! Quotes are needed.

```
<i class="icon-home" ng-class="{'icon-white': someBooleanValue}">
```

UPDATE:

In older versions of Angular, using a backslash also does the trick, but not in the newer versions.

```
<i class="icon-home" ng-class="{icon\-white: someBooleanValue}">
```

The former is probably preferred, since you can more easily search for it in your favorite editor.

Comment: THANK YOU for this. I've wasted WAY TOO MUCH time on this one, too.

Comment: Thank you!!!  I knew this was happening but I was unsure how to resolve.  THANKS!

Comment: I use AngularJS 1.2.3. The "\-" doesn't work for me. "''" worked very well.

Comment: Was wondering why this wasn't working for me when I seemed to be following other examples!

Comment: $scope.someBooleanValue = true

Answer (score 11):

`\'icon-white\'` works as well (with AngularJS 1.2.7)

Comment: This is the best answer as it is the most future-friendly and backwards compatible

Comment: Hi! @EricSteinborn I'm from the future, I've come here to warn you: This is not friendly at all!

Answer (score 0):

alternative for uses ng-class :

```
    .menu-disabled-true{
color: red;
}
    .menu-disabled-false{
color: green;
}


<div ng-controller="DeathrayMenuController">
<p class=menu-disabled-{{status}}>shanam</p>
 <button ng-click="action()">click me</button>
</div>

<script>



function DeathrayMenuController($scope) {
    $scope.status=true
    $scope.action= function(){
      $scope.status=!$scope.status
    }
}
</script>
```