# ngClass not working when calling a css class diferently?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, ng-class

Im having a problem, more like trouble understanding why a code does/doesn't work while using ngClass directive.
I have this css class inside the component.css

```
.yellow-text {
    color: yellow;
}
```

In the component.html I have this simple paragraph, nameTest is a property from the component which has the value 'Testing'.

```
<p [ngClass]="{ yellow-text: nameTest === 'Testing' }">ASDASD</p>
```

This doesn't compile unless I add ' ' in yellow-text.

```
<p [ngClass]="{ 'yellow-text': nameTest === 'Testing' }">ASDASD</p>
```

On the other hand, if I make the css class look like this

```
.yellowtext {
    color: yellow;
}
```

I can use this code.

```
<p [ngClass]="{ yellowtext: nameTest === 'Testing' }">ASDASD</p>
```

Why? What am I missing? Sorry for asking this, im probably missing something fundamental.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557151/ngclass-style-with-dash-in-key

Comment: @racraman Thanks, I wasn't sure how to search this.

Comment: glad to help :)   What I find works well with searching is the main "outer" topics followed by the specifics - so in this case, I found the article by googling 'ngclass hyphen`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it does not compile with no quotes, be they single or double, is because `ngClass` expects an object, and in Javascript, object keys don't need quotes if they only contain characters, numbers and underscores, if the keys have special characters like `-` in your case, you have to put quotes around them. For example

`{this is not valid: 'Not OK'}` is not a valid object syntax, to make it valid, you put quotes around the key `{'this is now valid': 'OK now'}`

Comment: Understood. Thanks for this information, seems a fundamental thing in Javascript. Will look into it.